# class not getting removed on focus - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```js
$("input.fee").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest("div.FirstLayer").removeClass("removeClass");
});
```

```css
.removeClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="FirstLayer removeClass">
    <input class="foo" value="fooX" />
  </div>
  <div class="SecondLayer">
    <div class="thirdLayer">
      <input class="fee" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is my class not getting removed on focus?.

Answer (score 4):

Your Selector is wrong

```
$("input.fee").focus(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.mainWrapper").find("div.FirstLayer").removeClass("removeClass");  
});
```

Working demo:

```js
$("input.fee").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest("div.mainWrapper").find("div.FirstLayer").removeClass("removeClass");
});
```

```css
.removeClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="FirstLayer removeClass"><input class="foo" value="fooX" /></div>

  <div class="SecondLayer">
    <div class="thirdLayer">
      <input class="fee" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[.closest(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its `ancestors` in the DOM tree.

---

**Problem**

`$("input.fee")` doesn't have the *ancestors* element `div.FirstLayer` see in the below image.

[image]

**Solution**

`$("input.fee").closest("div.mainWrapper")`  get the *ancestors* element `div.mainWrapper` and than find the element `div.FirstLayer`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: bacause input.fee does not have `div.FirstLayer` as any parent.